# Qt connect works, what is the equivalent disconnect method?

Tags: c++, qt, signals, connect, disconnect

I have a connect that works which connects a signal in C++ to a slot in JavaScript:

```
    Object::connect(this, &clsQtPushBtn::clicked
                   ,[pobjScriptEng, strCall, strFile, strScript]() {
                       QString strScriptWithCall = static_cast<QString>(strStript)
                                                 + static_cast<QString>(strCall) + "();";
                       pobjScriptEng->evaluate(strScriptWithCall);
                   });
```

In the above code:

this is an instance of my PushButton class clsQtPushBtn.
clsQtPushBtn::clicked is the address of the "clicked" signal.
pobjScriptEng is a pointer to an instance of QJSEngine*.
strCall is a JavaScript function "test".
strFile is the name of the JavaScript file "simon2.js".
strScript is the content of the JavaScript file which contains the function test().

The question is how do a make the equivalent disconnect call as I'm having difficulty with it, there are 7 options and just changing connect for disconnect does not work, I get:

```
    no matching member function for call to 'disconnect'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [QObject::connect](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qobject.html#connect-4) function returns a [QMetaObject::Connection](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmetaobject-connection.html) so you can pass it to [QObject::disconnect](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qobject.html#disconnect-4).

Answer (score 0):

Normally, you would just provide the same details as in the `connect` call (for example, source and target objects, source signal and target slot).

However, that *particular* `connect` form you're using returns a `QMetaObject::Connection` object which you can store for later disconnection:

```
auto connection = Object::connect(this, &clsQtPushBtn::clicked, blah, blah);
:
QObject::disconnect(connection);
```

That's most likely a better way, since it can get the information *immediately* rather than searching for a connection in a possibly large list (though I may be wrong about how that's implemented). It's *especially* better since I believe it's the *only* option in this case, seeing that every lambda is unique, so you couldn't use a new one to find the old connection anyway.

In addition, I've used a local variable to store it but you'd probably be better storing it into a member variable of some sort.